# Empire changed leadership and became more noticeably evil somehow?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In George Lucas's novel of A New Hope, Biggs tells Luke that the Empire was a paradise at first and then became dystopian.  He says:

> "The empire may have been great and beautiful once, but the people in charge now, it's rotten, Luke, rotten."

What change of leadership is he referring to?  The emperor was in charge of the empire the whole time.  Is he referring to Vader becoming a bigger player?

Comment: Lucas Retcon #8,675,309

Comment: Taken loosely, it could mean "the body which is now the Empire" - i.e. the Galactic Republic, with Palpatine being "the people in charge now".

Comment: Well, we know that the senate was on the verge of being disbanded...

Comment: Maybe he was referring to Jar Jar.

Comment: @Richard Was disbanded, it's talked about around the Death Star meeting table in New Hope

Comment: @Richard - flaggesa as offensivisa

Comment: @DVK - Meesa so sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The rise of the Imperial Grand Moffs and the expansion of the Tarkin doctrine

While this smells on the surface of something that might have received the classic George Lucas retcon treatment, Biggs may be referring to the rise of the Grand Moffs as governors of the Oversectors — in particular, the reorganization and further militarization of the Oversectors that occurred around 5 BBY.

[Grand Moff Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wilhuff_Tarkin) became the first Grand Moff of the Galactic Empire shortly after the founding of the Empire and Luke's birth.  As more Grand Moffs were assigned to regions of the Empire, and as more of them fell into line with the "Tarkin doctrine" — a policy based on fear and intimidation — the Empire would have become a harsher place, with the freedoms enjoyed during the Republic giving way to measures designed to prevent rebellion.

From the Star Wars Wikia entry on ["Grand Moff"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Moff):

> **The Tarkin Doctrine called for rule of the galaxy through fear of overwhelming force**, and recommended the creation of superweapons such as the Death Star to create terror of Imperial reprisal that would **stifle any thoughts of rebellion**. Delighted, Palpatine made Tarkin the first Grand Moff, giving him control of nearly the entire Outer Rim.

There would have been an increase in the severity of Oversector policies around 5 BBY, consistent with Biggs' observations:

> In the course of the Empire's further militarization (ca. 5 BBY), Moff Wilhuff Tarkin submitted a special holocommunique to Palpatine suggesting a reorganization of these oversectors as part of his Tarkin Doctrine. This was an attempt to cope with the problems of increasing Rebel activity across sector lines. Palpatine evidently approved of this suggestion, and acted accordingly...

Given that Grand Moff Tarkin himself was an important character in *A New Hope*, the changes that Biggs laments in the novelization could very well be this further militarization by the leadership of the Oversectors.

Comment: None of that Moff stuff is canon tho'. It's worse than that General vs Admiral nonsense.

Comment: @Gaius : It's precisely because the Tarkin doctrine comes from C-canon and S-canon material now deemed "Legends" that I only gave the Wikia links (and not specific lists of works).  But canon status or not, certain things *must* have happened between episodes III and IV.  Tarkin did become a Grand Moff, he was a powerful figure in the Empire, and he was pursuing a strict anti-Rebel policy in the time leading up to the Battle of Yavin.